# Insert/show Google Form using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, insert, google-forms, google-sites

Is it possible to insert/show a Google Form in a Google Site using Google Apps Script?

My code looks like this:

```
  var encontrado=0;
  for (var i=1; i < array_filas ; i++){
    if (valor == datos[i][0]){
      encontrado=1;
      App.getElementById('form').setVisible(true);
    }
  }

  if(encontrado==0){
    App.getElementById('error').setVisible(true); 
  }
```

I ask the user for a number, if the number is correct then I'd like to show a Google Form in the Google Site. Or at least redirect him to the Google Form url.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to insert a Google Form into a Google Site:

[Documentation - Google](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en)

There is a **Sites** Service in Google Apps Services:

[Documentation - Google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/)

Looks like you can dynamically add a page to a Google Site:

[Documentation - Sites Page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page)

New pages in a Google site have a different URL for each page:

> https://sites.google.com/site/yourSiteName/thePageName

I wonder if this would work to open the page:

[Documentation - Get Page by URL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#getPageByUrl(String))